# wxformbuilder and unicode labels

Tags: wxformbuilder

Is there a way to get Unicode characters into label code generated by wxFormBuilder?

For example, to get an Angstrom character the generated string should read `u"\u212b"`.

I tried entering `\u212b` in the label property field but the resulting string reads `u"u212b"`.  So I tried escaping the backslash as `\\u212b` but that gave me `u"\\u212b"`.

I'm using wxFormBuilder v3.5 - beta.  Generating Python code, although the C++ code shows the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, wxFormBuilder includes this command (*# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-* 
) on the first line at least for the python code generated.

So I went into MS word and inserted the Angstrom character Å, I then copied it into wxFormBuilder *(Version 3.5 - RC1)* statictext control and it worked on running the code.

[image]

[image]

Try my approach above instead of typing "u212b". Or type directly in your code like so: u"Hello... Å"

Comment: Thanks Umar.  I don't have MS Word but your answer reminded me about Character Map.  That works fine.